# Pandas - change in value to negative with a specific condition for particular groups of values

Tags: python, pandas

I have an example of a df that looks like this:

```
   Group   0       1       Total      
0    1     Text    5        5
1    1     Text2   5        5
2    1     SUM     10       10
3    2     10%     10       10
4    2     100%    100      100
5    2     SUM     110      110
6    3     Text3   4        4
7    3     SUM     4        4
```

Each row is divided into groups - in this case groups from 1 to 3 - the number of groups is different, but this does not matter.

I would like all elements in `df[0]` being number and `%` sign (e.g. 10% or 100%) to change their value in `Total` column to negative values
An example of such a solution:

```
   Group   0       1       Total      
0    1     Text    5        5
1    1     Text2   5        5
2    1     SUM     10       10
3    2     10%     10       -10    <--- change the value here
4    2     100%    100      -100   <--- change the value here
5    2     SUM     110      110
6    3     Text3   4        4
7    3     SUM     4        4
```

as far as I can pull this off, I don't know how to change these values. I've tried that way:
`df[df[0].str.contains('\d%', regex= True, na=False)]`

This way I have all the rows in which the value of `df[0]` have these requirements - the problem is that I don't know how to change their value in the `Total` column to negative. I tried that, but it doesn't help and there are errors:
`df['Total'] = np.where(df[df[0].str.contains('\d%', regex= True, na=False)], df['Total'] *= -1,  df['Total'])`

In addition, I would like to change the value `df[0] == SUM`  to a negative value but only when all the elements in the same group as SUM were values that met the previous requirements. 

Example:

```
   Group   0       1       Total      
0    1     Text    5        5
1    1     Text2   5        5
2    1     SUM     10       10
3    2     10%     10       -10  
4    2     100%    100      -100 
5    2     SUM     110      -110   <--- here should be a negative value - they are in the same group 
6    3     Text3   4        4
7    3     SUM     4        4
```

if in a given group (in this case group 2) there are values which for `df[0]` contain only a number and a sign of percentage, then their values for the `Total` column should be negative. Additionally, if all rows in the group meet this condition (these are numbers with a percentage sign) then for `df[0] == SUM` the value in `Total` column should also change the sign. 

How to connect it to such a regex? How to make `SUM` dependence in a given group on previous values in same group?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
#test number with %
m = df[0].str.contains('\d%', regex= True, na=False)

#multiple if matched condition
df.loc[m, 'Total'] *= -1

#test if all values without last are matched m condition    
m1 = m.groupby(df['Group']).transform(lambda x: x[:-1].all())

#multiple last value of group if matched m1 and not matched m
df.loc[m1 & ~m, 'Total'] *= -1
print (df)
   Group      0    1  Total
0      1   Text    5      5
1      1  Text2    5      5
2      1    SUM   10     10
3      2    10%   10    -10
4      2   100%  100   -100
5      2    SUM  110   -110
6      3  Text3    4      4
7      3    SUM    4      4
```

Comment: This works very well - how can I add other conditions for searching these rows? - e.g. sometimes I have such exceptions that the `%` character is in `df[1]` and only a number in `df[0]`. How to add this regex in `.str.contains` to add such additional condition (if `df[0]` is a number and at the same time` df[1]` is a `%` character) make a new `m`?

Comment: @DeepSea - Then use `m = df[0].str.contains('\d%', regex= True, na=False) & df[1].str.contains('\d%', regex= True, na=False)`

Comment: @jezreal I interested in a solution where `df[0]` and at the same time in this case `df[1]` is a `%` sign -more or less something like that, but it does not work: `m = df[0].str.contains('\d%', regex= True, na=False) or (df[0].str.contains('\d', regex= True, na=False) & df[1].str.contains('%', regex= True, na=False))`

Comment: @DeepSea - It seems more complicated, I am lost. Maybe the best create new question with changed conditions.

Comment: it was my syntax error - this works fine for other cases - just add new conditions here `m = df[0].str.contains('\d%', regex= True, na=False) | (df[0].str.contains('\d', regex= True, na=False) & df[1].str.contains('%', regex= True, na=False))`

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
df.loc[df['0'].str.contains("%"), "Total"] *= -1

df.loc[df.groupby("Group")['Total']
           .transform(lambda x : x * -1 if any(x < 0) else x) < 0, "Total"] *= -1
```

output,

```
   idx  Group      0    1  Total
0    0      1   Text    5      5
1    1      1  Text2    5      5
2    2      1    SUM   10     10
3    3      2    10%   10    -10
4    4      2   100%  100   -100
5    5      2    SUM  110   -110
6    6      3  Text3    4      4
7    7      3    SUM    4      4
```